# JSF how to change alignment of link

Tags: html, css

Here is the html output of my view. The problem is  text-decoration is working well but text-align is not working.

```
<div class="ui-layout-unit-content ui-widget-content" style="position: relative; height: 23px; visibility: visible;">
   <a href="secure_logout" style="text-decoration: blink;text-align: right">Logout</a>
</div>
```

I also tried Css but it doesn't working.

```
element.style {
   color: #D20005;
   font-weight: bold;
   text-decoration: #D20005 !important;
   text-align: right !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `display: block;` or `display: inline-block;` to your `a` then only it will be alligned to right.

> Because before applying the display properties its default value is inline and inline element cannot have the width and without width it can't be aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [this](http://jsfiddle.net/WuvRz/1/)

```
    <div class="aligndiv" style="text-align:center;">
        <a href="secure_logout" style="text-decoration: blink;text-align:center">Logout</a>
    </div>
```